# Как работать с несколькими таблицами sqlite-net-plc

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Создал несколько таблиц

```
public TodoItemDatabase(string dbPath)
{
    database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    database.CreateTableAsync<OneTable>().Wait();
    database.CreateTableAsync<OtherTable>().Wait();
   }
```

Создал методы сохранения в одном файле

```
public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(ModelOneTable item)
{
  if (item.ID != 0)
  {
    return database.UpdateAsync(item);
  }
  else {
    return database.InsertAsync(item);
  }
}
public Task<int> SaveItemAsyncOther(OtherTable item)
{
  if (item.ID != 0)
  {
    return database.UpdateAsync(item);
  }
  else {
    return database.InsertAsync(item);
  }
}
```

Работает только один метод, не пойму почему.
рыскал интернет в поисках реализации, нашёл это https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99740/database-table-sqlite-to-separate-database-to-table-declarations сейчас у меня реализовано как раз для каждой таблице из базы данных свои методы(все методы в одном файле). Еще человек на форуме рекомендовал использовать дженерики но я понял до конца как это реализовать.
Да. и дженереки мне не подходят(наверно) так как для каждой таблице уникальные запросы. Можно наверно конечно и через СИшарп потом запросы писать, но мне проше составлять запросы на языке sql.

Answer (score 0):

Так вы создаете первую таблицу, используя в качестве модели данных класс OneTable, а в методе для сохранения используете другой класс ModelOneTable. Исправьте и все должно работать, если классы корректно определены.